# How to perform iteration in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, subquery

I have a query that I need to perform 1000 times. Each time i need to increment two filter values within that query.

```
select min(a), min(bo
from(select*
from(select unmatchedpow.id, unmatchedpow.ut_sec-difference AS A, unmatchedpow.ut_sec-difference AS B
from(select*
from(select unmatchedpow.ut_sec-unmatchedsaaf.ut_sec AS difference,*
from(select*from unmatchedpow, unmatchedsaaf 
order by unmatchedpow.id))))
where unmatchedpow.id between 0 and 1)
```

So with each iteration the last between statement parameters increment by 1, ie between 1 and 2, then between 2 and 3... up until 999 and 1000.

is there any way i can do this and store the results as well?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Whilst some experienced users will be able to help, the structure of your question does not make it easy to understand exactly what your issue is. Please use code blocks for your SQL, and make sure your SQL is valid and compiles

Comment: There's no reason to do `select * from (select ...)`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am doing my question correctly but i have around 995 different values in column 1 and the same amount in column 2, I want to find the closest observation from column 2 to the first observation in column 1 and repeat the process for all the observations in col 1

Answer (score 1):

Create a table that contains the numbers from `0` to `999`, and join with that to get the values for the `BETWEEN` test.

```
SELECT n.num, min(x.a), min(x.b)
from number_table AS n
LEFT JOIN (select*
    from(select unmatchedpow.id, unmatchedpow.ut_sec-difference AS A, unmatchedpow.ut_sec-difference AS B
        from(select*
            from(select unmatchedpow.ut_sec-unmatchedsaaf.ut_sec AS difference,*
                from(select*from unmatchedpow, unmatchedsaaf)))) AS x
ON x.id BETWEEN n.num AND n.num+1
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I am doing my question correctly but i have around 995 different values in column 1 and the same amount in column 2, I want to find the closest observation from column 2 to the first observation in column 1 and repeat the process for all the observations in col 1

Comment: I thought you wanted to do it for every number from 0 to 999, whether or not it actually exists in the table.

Comment: i am just looking for the closest match to the observations in column 1 from column. I do apologise I am finding it difficult to put into words what i am trying to do

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the result you're trying to get from it?

Comment: col 1 (210, 242,274,306,338) col 2 (213, 235,295,355,415) so the closest points to col1 from column 2 would be (213,235,295,295,355)

Comment: Edit the question. Show the input tables and the desired output. Even better would be to create a sample at sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: So `between n and n+1` has nothing to do with what you're really trying to do?